# How to connect the VNA to RF transmission line for antenna tuning?

Tags: antenna, bluetooth, vna, tuning

I am working on a 2.45 GHz(Bluetooth) project. the design has a Chip antenna with 50 Ω impedance trace to connect antenna and chip.

I intend to tune the antenna impedance using the Pi network using VNA.

I have a basic VNA (I bought it on Amazon). I have read this guide [link](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-AN91445_Antenna_Design_and_RF_Layout_Guidelines-ApplicationNotes-v09_00-EN.pdf?fileId=8ac78c8c7cdc391c017d073e054f6227), and in section 15, it says: *"Connect a 10 pF capacitor from the first pad going from the 50 Ω reference point to the antenna tip.
There should always be a capacitor between the coaxial cable and the antenna. This blocks the DC to and from the network analyzer"*

The design follows the same as follows:

[image]

I have a u.FL connector where I plan to connect the network analyzer, but I don't know what best practices say about connecting the VNA to an RF transmission line.

[image]

the question is should I remove the L5 and C20 and connect the VNA to mesuare the impedance and  tune the antenna?

Comment: Do your calibration with the cable connected to the VNA.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.